# Как здесь расставить знаки препинания?!

Tags: пунктуация

Мы говорим: пушкинский Петербург – и в памяти возникают совершенно определённые образы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мне кажется, что подойдет такое оформление:

Мы говорим "пушкинский Петербург" – и в памяти возникают совершенно определённые образы.

1) После "мы говори" не стоит ставить двоеточие, так как это лишняя остановка голоса. Лучше применить упрощенное оформление прямой речи в виде дополнения.

2) Тире здесь авторский знак, заменяющий запятую,  второе предложение имеет присоединительный характер, а остановка голоса делит сообщение на две части, сопоставляя их.

Сравнить:

Я тронул их – и горестно в тиши раздался звук.

На лице её появилась холодная неподвижность и важность – и я не узнавал её.

Answer (score 0):

Говорим "партия" - предполагаем "Ленин". Просто предложение.

Мы говорим: "пушкинский Петербург", – и в памяти возникают совершенно определённые образы.
Сложносочиненное предложение, два субъекта (мы и образы) - разделяем запятой. Тире подчеркивает следствие, моментальность действия. У Розенталя, кстати, описан знак ", -".

С другой стороны, достаточно одного тире (имхо).

А вообще "высшая" пунктуация реально не разработана. Например, не ясно, что главнее: ":" или ";". Поэтому возможна неправильная трактовка структуры мысли. Недостаток места не позволяет привести примеры. Возможно, понадобится введение новых знаков, например: "::", ";;" или ",,". Вполне возможен знак отрицания, замена слову "нет": "--".